# Only change image src for container that is collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two listeners on when the containers open or close.

But all images change when a container opens, and all images change when a container closes at the same time.

I only want the the container that was opened to changed to minus and the rest remain as plus images and vice versa.

I am using bootstrap for the collapsible container functionality.

Below is what I currently have:

```js
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  $(this).find(".panel-icon").attr('src', 'https://s22.postimg.org/hkrauaofx/Mathematic_Minus2.png');
});

$('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  $(this).find(".panel-icon").attr('src', 'https://s22.postimg.org/9takvqkal/Mathematic_Plus2.png');
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 75%;
}
.head {
  background: #D9DBDE;
}
.panel-heading {
  background-color: #D9DBDE;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.panel-title {
  font-size: 21px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  color: #4F5858;
  line-height: 1.3;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.panel-icon {
  width: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <form action="/update" id="formwrite">
    <div class="panel-group secondary-bridge container" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
          <h4 class="panel-title va-middle">Tab 1
      <img src='https://s22.postimg.org/9takvqkal/Mathematic_Plus2.png' data-swap='../images/coll.svg' class="panel-icon collapse-icon" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collaspeOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collaspeOne">
      </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collaspeOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
          <div class="panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              Tab 1
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body row fieldpos">
              <fieldset class="form-group textwide">
                <label for="vmrecord">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="vmrecord" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
          <h4 class="panel-title va-middle">Tab 2
        <img src='https://s22.postimg.org/9takvqkal/Mathematic_Plus2.png' data-swap='../images/coll.svg' class="panel-icon collapse-icon" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collaspeTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collaspeTwo">
        </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collaspeTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
          <div class="panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              Tab 2
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
          <h4 class="panel-title va-middle">Tab 3
         <img src='https://s22.postimg.org/9takvqkal/Mathematic_Plus2.png' data-swap='../images/coll.svg' class="panel-icon collapse-icon" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collaspeThree" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collaspeThree">
         </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collaspeThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
          <div class="panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              Tab 3
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFour">
          <h4 class="panel-title">Tab 4
          <img src='https://s22.postimg.org/9takvqkal/Mathematic_Plus2.png' data-swap='../images/coll.svg' class="panel-icon collapse-icon" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseFour">
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFour">
          <div class="panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              Tab 4
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFive">
          <h4 class="panel-title">Tab 5
           <img src='https://s22.postimg.org/9takvqkal/Mathematic_Plus2.png' data-swap='../images/coll.svg' class="panel-icon collapse-icon" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseFive">
           </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFive">
          <div class="panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              Tab 5
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

And here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/04uL9tqh/21/)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I have used `.panel` instead of `#accordion`, with `#accordion` `(this).find` will find all `img` in it.

```
$('.panel').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  $(this).find(".panel-icon").attr('src', 'https://s22.postimg.org/hkrauaofx/Mathematic_Minus2.png');
});

$('.panel').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  $(this).find(".panel-icon.collapsed").attr('src', 'https://s22.postimg.org/9takvqkal/Mathematic_Plus2.png');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/04uL9tqh/24/

Answer (score 0):

Below is a native and safe way. I've also updated your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/salih0vicX/04uL9tqh/23/

```
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  $(e.target).data('bs.collapse').$trigger.attr('src', 'https://s22.postimg.org/hkrauaofx/Mathematic_Minus2.png');
});

$('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(e, f) {
  $(e.target).data('bs.collapse').$trigger.attr('src',  'https://s22.postimg.org/9takvqkal/Mathematic_Plus2.png');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `$('#accordion')` to `$('.panel')` like this :

```
$('.panel').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  $(this).find(".panel-icon").attr('src', 'https://s22.postimg.org/hkrauaofx/Mathematic_Minus2.png');
});

$('.panel').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  $(this).find(".panel-icon").attr('src', 'https://s22.postimg.org/9takvqkal/Mathematic_Plus2.png');
});
```

here is [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/04uL9tqh/27/)